# fusermount prepends /home to path when resource is busy

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting, sshfs, unmount

### Problem:

I created a `bash` script for SSHFS mount/unmount using:

```
1|  dir=$(mktemp -d)
2|  sshfs user@server $dir
3|  cd $dir
4|  bash
5|  fusermount -u $dir
6|  rmdir $dir
```

Once these lines are executed, an error occurs on line 5 for `fusermount -u $dir` and gives this message:

```
fusermount: failed to unmount /home/tmp/tmp.xxxxxxxxxx: Device or resource busy
```

In the warning message, `/home` is prepended to the path instead of only `/tmp/tmp.xxxxxxxxxx`. Interestingly, `rmdir` then gives this message:

```
rmdir: failed to remove '/tmp/tmp.xxxxxxxxxx': Device or resource busy
```

... showing that `$dir` still has the value of `/tmp/tmp.xxxxxxxxxx`.

### Question:

**Why does `fusermount` prepend `/home` to the path when the resource is busy?**

Comment: Why are you starting `bash` on the Line 4?

Comment: So I can run commands in the directory. Once I exit this bash, then the unmounting and `rmdir` occurs.

Comment: Maybe the "_Device or resource busy_" Error Message is appearing just because of the "`cd $dir`" Command. The Directory referenced through the `$dir` Variable is still in use. Try adding a "`cd ..`" Command just before the "`fusermount -u $dir`" Command and try again.

Comment: Hi @DOBRESCU_Mihai! It worked! Thanks for the tip! :-)

Comment: _For Great Success_, @Majal. I shall add now an Exquisite Answer to this Question so that the whole Planet will be able to rejoice in ecstasy forever.

Comment: Interesting. I totally missed the fact that the shell is in the working directory. My attention was on the fact that the message had a prepended `/home`. I'll check with `fusermount` if this is a bug or something.

Comment: There is no `fusermount` Bug. It displays that Error Message because it attempts to work inside the `$dir` Directory. The same thing happens to the `rmdir $dir` Command. If they are run outside of it, then they are working. Either with my `cd ..` addition or with @Tom Yan's `(cd $dir;bash)` Trick, you are avoiding running them inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is the Correct Version that has solved this Problem:

```
1|  dir=$(mktemp -d)
2|  sshfs user@server $dir
3|  cd $dir
4|  bash
5|  cd ..
6|  fusermount -u $dir
7|  rmdir $dir
```

Comment: Or you can group `cd $dir` and `bash` to `(cd $dir; bash)`

Comment: Why? Does the group annihilate the changing of the directory to `$dir` after `bash` exists?

Comment: Try it and see. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html

Comment: I cannot test right now. I understand that "_each of the commands in `list` [are] to be executed in that subshell_", which is extremely cool - quite freezing, actually. When the subshell terminates, the whole Planet explodes and the current directory is reverted back to the one that was present before the group got executed. This is too subtle for most people. I would not have started that `bash` command just like that, in the first place.

Comment: Funny. It does not work. As you can see [here](https://i.imgur.com/d0YQKrH.png). Maybe you are using another Flavor of the _Bourne-Again_ Shell-Scripting Environment. I am using _CygWin_'s.

Comment: Weird. I have just pressed the Control-D Key Combination in order to get out of the Terminal Window, as I am usually doing. And an `exit` Command has appeared! As you can see [here](https://i.imgur.com/rWViNBB.png). That means that the `bash` Session did not exit after the end of the Group Execution! The Second Control-D Key Combination has produced the Usual `logout` Command, as you can see [here](https://i.imgur.com/9sPRC5q.png). Can you explain that?

Comment: Uhm, wasn't that the idea of the OP? He wanted an interactive shell in the middle of a script.

Comment: You have not answered my previous questions. Related to the Interactive Shell - all that I can say it is that it is a very weird idea. It is basically mixing the Automated Non-Interactive Nature of a Shell-Script with the Manual Interactive Nature of an Interactive Shell. I can bet that it might be done in a different way.

Comment: I mean, it worked in you tests as expected as that was the idea. The `cd` was to prepare for the / another interactive shell that you were going to start. The command group isn't finished until you manually exit the shell.

Comment: As for `exit` v.s. `logout`, it depends on whether the "current" shell is a "login shell". If you run `bash -l` in the group instead, you'll also see `logout` instead of `exit` the first time you control-D.

Comment: You were probably thinking of the result of `(cd /; bash -c "pwd")` instead btw.

Comment: Nope. I was thinking _exactly_ of your `(cd $dir; bash)` Version as another Solution for this Problem. As you can see in my Previous Tests that appear in those Three Screen-Shots, it does _not_ work. The Current Directory _stays_ `/` (the Root Directory) even after the Manual Exiting of the Secondary `bash` Shell. It should have reverted back to the `/home/dobre/` Directory. But it does _not_.

Comment: On a second thought, I can see now that actually I was mistaken the `/` Root Directory for the `~/` Home Directory. So the Tests _are really_ working. Maybe you _could_ create another Answer for this Question with your own Version.